# Could be in mathematics an open problem solved by another open problem ?if yes any example?

Tags: examples-counterexamples, open-problem

In mathematics there are many open problems or open conjectures some of them had been solved and others are still open , it is good to know if there exist an example of open problem wich is solved by another open problem ? In logic I never saw problem which solve other problem !!!

Comment: The Generalized Riemann Hypothesis has many consequences, as does the $abc$ conjecture.

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis#Analytic_criteria_equivalent_to_the_Riemann_hypothesis for a start.

Comment: [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17209/consequences-of-the-riemann-hypothesis) is a brief discussion of some of the many consequences of the GRH.

Comment: Do you meant if we assume RH true or false we will get other problems solved ?

Comment: That is certainly implied by equivalence. Look for NP-complete problems.

Comment: If we assume the GRH is true then the consequences follow.

Comment: I do not remember the exact statement, but there is a statement which was proven true if the Riemann hypothesis is true, and then proven true, if the Riemann hypothesis is false. So, this problem actually has been solved by the open Riemann hypothesis.